# how to get non overlapping sets from integer sets?

Tags: algorithm

I need help!

I want to know efficient algorithms for get answer from this problem.

problem: get maximum number of sets can be chosen from given sets

sets = {1,2,4}, {2,3,4}, {3,4,5}, {1,2,6}, {2,3,5}

expected answer is 2! {1,2,6}, {3,4,5}

how can I get the answer when the sets become numerous? Isn't there any algorithm can solve this problem?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independent_set_(graph_theory) (In the graph, each set is a node, having edges to all other sets (nodes) it shares an element with)

Comment: @tobias_k thank you for the answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is an instance of the [Maximum independent set problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independent_set_(graph_theory)).

Using python and networkx' [maximum_independent_set](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.approximation.clique.maximum_independent_set.html#networkx.algorithms.approximation.clique.maximum_independent_set):

```py
from networkx import Graph
from networkx.algorithms.approximation.clique import maximum_independent_set
from itertools import combinations

V = [frozenset(s) for s in [{1,2,4}, {2,3,4}, {3,4,5}, {1,2,6}, {2,3,5}]]
E = [(x,y) for x,y in combinations(V, 2) if x&y] # "if x&y" means "if intersection of sets x and y is non-empty"
G = Graph()
G.add_nodes_from(V)
G.add_edges_from(E)

print( maximum_independent_set(G) )
# {frozenset({1, 2, 6}), frozenset({3, 4, 5})}
```

Note that networkx' `maximum_independent_set` function uses an approximation algorithm, i.e. in a big graph, the maximal independent set it finds might not be of maximum size. The documentation page links the research paper detailing the algorithm, and comments: *"The problem of finding such a set is called the maximum independent set problem and is an NP-hard optimization problem. As such, it is unlikely that there exists an efficient algorithm for finding a maximum independent set of a graph."*

Comment: Thank you for the answer!